# Let the Homomorphism $f$ be given by $f: \text{Pol}_3 \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2}, f(p(x)) = (p'(0), p(1))$ Find a basis for Kernel and Image of $f$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vector-spaces, vectors

Let the Homomorphism $f$ be given by

$$f: \text{Pol}_3 \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2}, f(p(x)) = (p'(0), p(1))$$

Find a basis for Kernel and Image of $f$.

---

We can write a third degree polynomial as:
$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$

The derivative is

$$3ax^2 + 2bx + c$$

So we have

$$p'(0) = 3a\cdot 0^2 + 2b \cdot 0 + c = c$$

and

$$p(1) = a\cdot1^3 + b\cdot1^2 + c \cdot 1 + d = a + b + c + d$$

What do I do now ? I know what the kernel and image mean, and that a basis needs to span the whole space in which it lies, but I'm not sure what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post an answer for $\ker f$, you should then try $\mathrm{Im}f$. I also assume that $\mathrm{Pol}_3(\mathbb R)$ is the space of polynomials of degree at most $3$, as you say.

If $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is in the kernel of your map, then $p'(0)=0$ and $p(1)=0$, and your calculations imply $c=0$ and $a+b+d=0$, so e.g. $d=-(a+b)$. Then your polynomial is of the form
$$p(x) = ax^3+bx^2-(a+b)=a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1).$$
This means that $\ker f$ is spanned by $x^3-1$ and $x^2-1$, and is thus two-dimensional as the two polynomials are linearly independent.

**Hint for $\mathrm{Im}f$**: the map is surjective, because for any pair $(u,v)\in \mathbb R^2$ you can consider the polynomial $p(x) = ux+(v-u) \in \mathrm{Pol}_3(\mathbb R)$, which has $(p'(0),p(1))=(u,v)$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused for the image. For the kernel it seem we can just set it equal to zero and solve for $a,b,c,d$. But for the image we cannot do that, right ? If we have $p(1) = a + b + c + d$ and $p'(0) = c$, can't we just take the vector $(1,1)$ as basis because we only have "values" of degree zero, without any $x$. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: No, I don't see what you mean. Your map is surjective if and only if its image corresponds to $\mathbb R^2$, hence the dimension (and a basis) should be clear.

Comment: The dimension is obviously two, and so we need two basis. If we have the standard basis $1,x,x^2,x^3$ and apply $f$ on it, we get $(1'(0), 1(1)) = (0,1)$, $(x'(0), x(1)) = (1,1)$, $((x^2)'(0), x^2(1)) = (0,1)$, $((x^3)'(0), x^3(1)) = (0,1)$, so we would have $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ as basis, would that be correct ? If we use your hint, we could have $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ as basis, right ?

Comment: Both bases are fine. The sentence "we need two basis" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since any element of the image can be written as $(c, a+b+c+d)$ and any element of $\Bbb{R}^2$ can be expressed in this form for an appropriate choice of $a, b, c$ and $d$, it follows that the image is all of $\Bbb{R}^2$. You shouldn't find it hard to come up with a basis for this space.

Now, if $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is in the kernel of $f$, we have $f(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=(c, a+b+c+d)$$=(0,0)$, implying that $c=0$ and $a+b+d=0$. Now at this point it's just clever trial and error to come up with a basis. We observe that $x^3-1$ and $x^2-1$ are both elements of the kernel and a quick calculation proves that they are linearly independent. We can use the rank-nullity theorem to check that the kernel of this function has dimension two (thus implying that we have found a basis). Alternatively, we can perform the calculation manually. Any element of the kernel can be written as: $$ax^3+bx^2-(a+b) = a(x^3-1) + b(x^2-1).$$

Comment: A basis for the image would be the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, is that correct ?

Comment: yup, thats right

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. It follows that $(p^\prime(0),p(1))=(c,a+b+c+d)$.

By definition, $\ker(f)=\{p(x)\in \text{Pol}_3\mathbb{R}|f(p(x))=(0,0)\}$. This implies that $$(p^\prime(0),p(1))=(0,0)\iff(c,a+b+c+d)=(0,0).$$ It follows that$$c=0 \ \ \text{and} \ \  d=-(a+b)\ \ .$$
Therefore, $p(x)=a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1)$. Therefore, $$\ker(f)=\{a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1)|a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$ This means that $x^3-1,x^2-1$ spans $\ker(f)$. Since $x^3-1,x^2-1$ is linearly independent, we can conclude that $x^3-1,x^2-1$ is a basis of $\ker(f)$.

By definition, $\text{Im}(f)=\{f(p(x))|p(x)\in\text{Pol}_3\mathbb{R}\}$. Therefore, $$\text{Im}(f)=\{(p^\prime(0),p(1))|p(x)\in\text{Pol}_3\mathbb{R}\}.$$ Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\text{Im}(f)&=\{(c,a+b+c+d)|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&=\{c(1,1)+(0,1)(a+b+d)|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}.
\end{align}
This means that $(1,1),(0,1)$ spans $\text{Im}(f)$. Since $(1,1),(0,1)$ is linearly independent, we can conclude that $(1,1),(0,1)$ is a basis of $\text{Im}(f)$.